# Helm Rep Add - is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached:error converting YAML to JSON: yaml mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Im trying to setup a Helm chart repo using Github pages. Everything appears to work fine with generating the index.yaml etc via Github Actions, awesome.

index.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  test:
  - apiVersion: v1
    created: "2021-08-27T09:54:44.830905882Z"
    description: Testing the chart releaser
    digest: b41b263d236ef9eee0a75e877982a10ea73face093b4999c6004263b041f0fad
    keywords:
    - test
    name: test
    urls:
    - https://github.com/xxx/xxx/releases/download/test-0.0.9/test-0.0.9.tgz
    version: 0.0.9
generated: "2021-08-27T09:54:44.587113879Z"
```

And a test chart

```
name: test
description: Testing the chart releaser
version: 0.0.9
apiVersion: v1
keywords:
  - test
sources:
home:
```

However, when i try to add the repo using

```
helm repo add test https://didactic-quibble-e0daddd0.pages.github.io/
```

I get the error

> Error: looks like "http://didactic-quibble-e0daddd0.pages.github.io/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 188: mapping values are not allowed in this context

The URL http://didactic-quibble-e0daddd0.pages.github.io/index.yaml returns the index.yaml file described above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different procedure and hope that helps you in hosting GitHub repo as a Helm Repo.

I have 2 Helm charts here:

- **Library**: this is going to be used by other helm charts as a
  dependency. This I am going to host in the below example as a helm repo on GitHub
- **App**: this is going to consume the **Library** chart and extra
  functionality.

**Library Chart: In your Library Directory**

```
helm package libchart
helm repo index .
```

Validate the index file is created and entries are correct

```
more index.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  libchart:
  - apiVersion: v2
    appVersion: 1.16.0
    created: "2022-11-30T08:57:01.109116+09:00"
    description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
    digest: 8aa38d70d61f81cf31627a7d7d9cc5c293f340bf01918c9a16ac1fac9fcc96e9
    name: libchart
    type: library
    urls:
    - libchart-0.1.0.tgz
    version: 0.1.0
generated: "2022-11-30T08:57:01.108194+09:00"
```

Commit "index.yaml" and ".tgz" files to the git repo.

Add helm repo:

```
helm repo add mylib --username parjun8840 --password TOPSECRET-TOKEN-FROM-GIT
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YOURGITUSER/helm-library/master
 
"mylib" has been added to your repositories

helm repo update
```

**App Chart: In your App Directory**

```
more Chart.yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: appchart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
dependencies:
  - name: libchart
    version: 0.1.0
    repository: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YOURGITUSER/helm-library/master
```

Then

```
helm dependency update 
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "mylib" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "newrelic" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading libchart from repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YOURGITUSER/helm-library/master
Deleting outdated charts
```